# C++ alternative for macro pasting

Tags: c++, macros

Let's say i have a series of classes:

```
class Port8Bit{
    void Write(uint8_t data);
    uint8_t Read();
};

class Port16Bit{
    void Write(uint16_t data);
    uint16_t Read();
};
//and so on for 32Bit and 64Bit
```

when i want to initiate the classes, instead of writing the code again for each class, i can use a macro:

```
#define intiatePort(portSize) { \
Port##portSize##Bit::Port##portSize##Bit(){ \
} \
  \
void Port##portSize##Bit::Write(uint##portSize##_t data){ \
  \  //write data 
} \
uint##portSize##_t Port##portSize##Bit::Read(){ \
    uint##portSize##_t result; \
    \    //read data 
    return result;  \

}
```

I'm quite new to CPP, but I've read that using macros in most cases is not a good practice. I would like to know, is there a better, more CPP-ish way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, use template

Comment: In a few years I hope we can answer this with Metaclasses/Templates completely, but for now templates are the closest you're going to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what templates are for:

```
template<class DataType>
class Port{
    void Write(DataType data);
    DataType Read();
};

using Port8Bit = Port<uint8_t>;
using Port16Bit = Port<uint16_t>;
// etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ answer here is to use templates:

```
template<Data> class Port {
  void Write(Data data);
  Data Read();
};
```

Then if you want an 8-bit version:

```
Port<uint8_t> port8bit;
```